GDM3 not starting Ubuntu 24.04 after gnome install
Google Cloud Platform, clean start from scratch.
I launch the GCP and create a new project
I select that project and create a new VM
Ubuntu 24.04 LTS ... plain vanilla, take defaults.  I start a terminal
window... no problem; it connects just fine.
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade --assume-yes
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
at about 99%, I see the message:

gdm.service is not active, cannot reload.
invoke-rc.d: initscript gdm3, action "reload" failed.

sudo reboot
Bricks!  I can't get into it to see the logs.

What I tried:
Before reboot, I purged ubuntu-desktop, it still bricks.
Tried installing slim... same behavior.
Tried other versions of 24.xx LTS (i.e. pro server, 24.10, minimal) no difference.
If I back up to Ubuntu 22.04, everything is fine.
I'm in as generic of a black box as I can get it.  I can start the VM, but I can't connect.  What diagnostic tools do I have?
